# How to append values in a excel sheet's column to a different list using openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, list, append, excel-2010, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook('excel.xlsx')

table=[]
Sheet_Name=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Input_Sheet')
for Indx_row, row in enumerate(Sheet_Name.iter_rows()):
    for cell_ind,cell in enumerate(row):
        if Indx_row==0:
            table.append(cell.value)


print table

Output:['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']
```

Now I want  to crate lists with names as  Col1, Col2,Col3,Col4

```
Col1=[]
Col2=[]
Col3=[]
Col4=[]
```

dynamically since excel sheet will be changing. Now I want to append corresponding column values to corresponding column lists.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl provides the `iter_cols()` method and `columns` property for columnar access.

Comment: I have edited my question. Will you please provide me a solution